# sudo -u (user) cmd not working in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, tomcat, sudo

I'm working in a bash script.

This bash script have to run command using `sudo -u (B) cmd`.

I execute this script using an user A.

in my `/etc/sudoers` i have all my commands declared.

When i execute it using terminal everything is fine.

When i execute it using a java program in a tomcat server i have mistake.

How i execute my script from my java program :

```
command = "/path/my-script.sh arg1"

 private String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

 }
```

In both (Terminal or Java program) case i execute those commands :

```
user=$(whoami)
echo "[INFO]: user = $user"
```

Result : `[INFO]: user = A`

```
mkdircmd=$(sudo -u B mkdir -p $project_path)
return_mkdircmd=$?

echo "[INFO]: mkdircmd: $mkdircmd / return mkdircmd: $return_mkdircmd"

cpcmd=$(sudo -u B cp $file_path $project_path)
return_cpcmd=$?


echo "[INFO]: cpcmd: $cpcmd / return cpcmd: $return_cpcmd"
```

Result :

With Tomcat server executing the script

```
[INFO]: mkdircmd:  / return mkdircmd: 1
[INFO]: cpcmd:  / return cpcmd: 1
```

With Terminal executing the script (./myscript)

```
[INFO]: mkdircmd:  / return mkdircmd: 0
[INFO]: cpcmd:  / return cpcmd: 0
```

Someone can help me to figure out where can be my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Does your tomcat server run with user id A? If it runs as another user, your sudoers file might not permit it to do a passwordless sudo. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, it does, because i'm runing **whoami** command and the result is **A**

Comment: Does user `A` have a password that must be entered when attempting to call `sudo`? Perhaps it runs on the command-line because you have already provided the password and it's been cached for that session. Try opening a new shell session and running that same script with `sudo` (or execute a `sudo -k` and re-run your script).

Answer (score 0):

To debug the problem change user to tomcat (assuming tomcat is running using tomcat user)

```
sudo su - tomcat
```

Execute the command:

```
sudo -u B (cmd)
```

debug for any errors. You might have to update the `/sbin/nologin` to `/bin/bash` in the `/etc/passwd` to `su` using tomcat.